# Math round и Math random образуют хвосты возле граничных значений

Tags: javascript, случайные-числа, округление

Если использовать Math.round то число округляется к ближайшему целому и функция Math.random даёт нам равномерное распределение, значит мы должны получить примерно одинаковое количество различных округлённых чисел при достаточном количестве генераций. Однако если запустить код ниже, то получаются хвосты у первого и последнего элемента. В среднем первый и последний элемент в 2 раза меньше чем все остальные.
Вопрос, почему так происходит?

```js
const numberArray = Array(500).fill(0)
for(let i=0;i<100000;i++){
    const rndNumber = Math.round(Math.random()*499)
    ++numberArray[rndNumber] 
}
console.log(numberArray[0], '- count first element')
console.log(numberArray[499], '- count last element')
console.log(numberArray[250], '- count 249')
console.log(numberArray[29], '- count 28')
console.log(numberArray[473], '- count 472')
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Это легко понять, если представить интервалы (дробных) значений, которые округляются к целым. У первого и последнего чисeл эти интервалы в два раза короче, чем у всех остальных.

Answer (score 0):

Посмотреть внимательно на эту картинку и подумать почему так.

```
> for(let i = 0; i < 30; i++) { console.log(i/10, Math.round(i/10), Math.ceil(i/10)); }
0 0 0
0.1 0 1
0.2 0 1
0.3 0 1
0.4 0 1
0.5 1 1
0.6 1 1
0.7 1 1
0.8 1 1
0.9 1 1
1 1 1
1.1 1 2
1.2 1 2
1.3 1 2
1.4 1 2
1.5 2 2
1.6 2 2
1.7 2 2
1.8 2 2
1.9 2 2
2 2 2
2.1 2 3
2.2 2 3
2.3 2 3
2.4 2 3
2.5 3 3
2.6 3 3
2.7 3 3
2.8 3 3
2.9 3 3
```

Comment: Почему Вы переписали мой ответ?